# How to place a clutter actor on a clutter texture?

Tags: c, gtk, gnome, glib, clutter

I have a clutter texture as my background . I need to put some clutter actors over it. is it possible to do it . Since i get the following error:

```
"invalid cast from `ClutterTexture' to `ClutterContainer' "
```

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClutterTexture is not a container, i.e. it cannot contain other actors.

ClutterBox and ClutterGroup are containers available in Clutter; ClutterBox allows using different layout managers - like ClutterBinLayout:

http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterBinLayout.html

or ClutterFixedLayout:

http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterFixedLayout.html

you can also use ClutterGroup, and use constraints to maintain a layout:

http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterConstraint.html

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I have used clutter but I will try to provide some insights. As the error says you cannot cast `ClutterTexture` to `ClutterContainer`. You can add actors only to container actors. If you want to setup background one of the options could be stacking of actors. You can stack other actors on top of the actor with background texture using layout managers. [This link](http://docs.clutter-project.org/docs/clutter-cookbook/1.0/layouts-stacking.html) provides some details which I think can be useful in your case.
Hope this helps!

Comment: but the layout managers does not allow child to be fixed in a particular position.

Comment: Can't [ClutterFixedLayout](http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/1.6/ClutterFixedLayout.html) or [ClutterConstraint](http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/1.6/ClutterConstraint.html) help you with that?